# Re-attach detached Terminal Tabs

Tags: command-line, 18.04, window, tabs

Is there a way in Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS that once a tab of "Terminal" window is detached from that window, to re-attach that tab to the another already opened Terminal window (with other tabs) again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, unfortunately it is one way only. You can detach a tab into a new window, but you cannot attach a terminal window as a tab to another terminal window.

Comment: Oh. Anyway, thanks for letting know about this

Comment: Arg, it was possible previously `16.04`.

Answer (score 2):

Try Mate Terminal on Ubuntu 18.04

It is available in apt:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mate-terminal
```

I use Mate Terminal (1.20.0) on Ubuntu 18.04, and I confirm that the workaround solution given by [Lior Bekerman](https://askubuntu.com/a/1372104/1641849) and [Kaz](https://askubuntu.com/a/1408737/1641849) works fine, as stated by Kaz:

"Detaching a terminal is performed by drag and drop, and if we create a dummy tab in the detached terminal, the original becomes a tab that we can drag and drop into the original window to reattach. Note: this operation seems to need the actual terminal payload window as a target, not the tab area above it. Dropping into the tab area will detach it, same as dropping into the desktop."

Answer (score 1):

You have your original terminal (from where your TAB was detached) - let's call it T1.
You have the detach TAB (which is actually a new terminal) - let's call it T2.

In T2 open a new TAB - now you have two TABs in T2.

Now you can detach the TAB you need by Drag & Drop it back to T1.

Then you can kill T2. :)

Comment: Welcome to Ask ubuntu :) , Well this doesn't works in the specified version 18.04 , So please I request you to read the full question and try if the answer works :)

Comment: Answer is useless; in the Gnome version that is in Ubuntu 18, dragging tabs only works within the same window, to rearrange their order.

Comment: Works for me on ubuntu 18.04, mate terminal 1.20

Comment: this does not work on Gnome terminal

Answer (score 1):

The trick described by [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1372104/110313) doesn't work in Gnome Terminal 3.28.2 in Ubuntu 18.

However, I just noticed that the same trick does work in MATE terminal 1.24.1 on Debian 11. Detaching a terminal is performed by drag and drop, and if we create a dummy tab in the detached terminal, the original becomes a tab that we can drag and drop into the original window to reattach. Note: this operation seems to need the actual terminal payload window as a target, not the tab area above it. Dropping into the tab area will detach it, same as dropping into the desktop.

I originally installed MATE on Debian because of a copy and paste problem: text copied and pasted from a Gnome terminal running in a guest VirtualBox turned double spaced (extra newlines) when pasted into anything in the host.

Looks like MATE provides a workaround for this reattach problem as well.

MATE is a fork of Gnome Terminal from the MATE project, which is a continuation of Gnome 2.